# How to properly use GtkFileChooserDialog for file opening in Glade?

Tags: c, gtk3, glade

How to add open button in GtkHeaderBar for GtkFileChooserDialog using Glade? I can't find single option in Glade, which let me do this basic thing. Can anybody know, how to find this option? I can't find single example how to do this on the internet.

When adding GtkFileChooserDialog, it looks like this (I have added one extra button to it at bottom, but imagine like it doesn't exist)

[image]
.

But it should like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

regarding your question:

to have a program be able to read from a file or from the user,

to read from a file:

```
myprogram  < myfile
```

To read from the user:

```
myprogram
```

Then have the actual program always read from `stdin`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Glade file which shows an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.22.1 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.20"/>
  <object class="GtkFileChooserDialog">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <property name="type_hint">dialog</property>
    <child type="titlebar">
      <object class="GtkHeaderBar">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkButton">
            <property name="label" translatable="yes">button</property>
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">True</property>
            <property name="receives_default">True</property>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="pack_type">end</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
    <child internal-child="vbox">
      <object class="GtkBox">
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
        <property name="spacing">2</property>
        <child internal-child="action_area">
          <object class="GtkButtonBox">
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="layout_style">end</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkComboBoxText">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <items>
                  <item translatable="yes">option 1</item>
                  <item translatable="yes">option 2</item>
                </items>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="expand">False</property>
            <property name="fill">False</property>
            <property name="position">0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. It seems to be missing the search button (with magnifying glass) though.